# maven generate web service in java

Tags: java, web-services, maven

I'm new to maven, and I want to use maven to generate the java code from a wsdl file (using the wsimport plugin ?), which is in my project (not in a url).

I think the wsdl file should be somewhere in myprojet/src/main/resources, and the generated sources in myproject/target/generatedsources/ws.

If the choice of these places ok ? If so, how can I create the sources from the wsdl to the designated folder using maven ? Can I choose the java package name of the sources ? Should I ?  Should I then make a jar file out of the sources ? How can I make sure that the generated sources are accessible for the compilation (in the classpath) ?

thank you.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057417/regarding-client-side-code-generation-from-wsdl/16058435#16058435

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this with the wsimport plugin, but most examples would require more knowledge of your pom.xml

[Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) is a popular free plugin for this exact purpose

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${cxf.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>generate-sources</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
            <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/myService.wsdl</wsdl>
                </wsdlOption>
            </wsdlOptions>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

NOTE:  You can definitely make a jar out of the generated sources, but this would be a separate entry inside your POM

Answer (score 0):

check out Apache's Axis2 -- it's designed specifically to help generate code based on an WSDL for web services. Basically it's exactly what you are looking for:

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/

EDIT: To expand, I typically will run the wsdl2java(.bat or .sh) file and point it to the wsdl (either on the web or local copy) and it generates everything else. It can even package it all into a jar for you (my preferred method because it's "cleaner"). You likely won't have any need to go into the generated code and change anything, you just end up adding that jar to your classpath then import like any other library and use it.